# How to get cart details from Cratejoy using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cratejoy

I'm developing custom frontend template for [cratejoy](http://docs.cratejoy.com/docs/cart-methods) and is hosted on their servers but after I subscribed to products via thier api I couldn't find any api to get my cart details so I'm wondering how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on the checkout page, there will be a cart object set. On other pages, you can access the object by calling `active_cart()`.

So on most pages you would do:

```
{% set cart = active_cart() %}
Cart id: {{ cart.id }}
Cart anon_id: {{ cart.anon_id }}
```

But on chechout.html you can simply do:

```
Cart id: {{ cart.id }}
Cart anon_id: {{ cart.anon_id }}
```

There's a partial list of cart properties on Cratejoy's [Page Variable Type](http://docs.cratejoy.com/docs/store-object-types#cart) document, but you may get a more complete list by calling `{{ cart.dict() }}`. In addition to what that displays, it will have several relations on it:

- cart.products

  cart.gifts (if you have the old verison of gifting--otherwise they're just under cart.products)

  cart.coupons

  cart.gift_cards

You can loop through these and access the objects in/on the cart. For example:

```
{% for coupon in cart.coupons %}
  {{ coupon.code_used }}
{% endfor %}
```

These other objects should be mostly covered in that same document linked above, but I generally just throw in a `{{ obj.dict() }}` whenever I want a real list of properties for an object.

It's also worth noting that when you hit the confirmation page after checkout, a new empty cart is created (with null anon_id, since you're now logged in). On thank_you.html, you'll generally want to be looking at the order object rather than the cart object.